# How do I use routerLink to navigate to route with auxiliary routes as a children in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Currently I'm trying to use `routerLink` this way to achieve my goal:

```
<a routerLink='/page/(tab1:foo//tab2:bar)' routeLinkActive="true">Click me!</a>
```

It throws an error saying that it's an unknown route.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a 
    [routerLink]="['/page', { outlets: { 'tab1': 'foo', 'tab2': 'bar' } }  ]" 
    routerLinkActive="active"
>
    Click me!!
</a>
```

Solution presented in question uses `(tab1:foo//tab2:bar)` as a param of `page` route.